# Spresenseメインボードのみでのデータ保存

Tags: spresense

Spresenseメインボードのみで、Flashへのデータ保存をしたいと思っています。
Arduino SDKではEEPROMライブラリがあるのですが、Spresense SDKには無いように見えます。
Spresense SDKで可能なのであれば、方法を教えて頂けると助かります。

Answer (score 1):

camera_main.c に以下のコードを見付けました。

```
/* In SD card is available, use SD card.
 * Otherwise, use SPI flash.
 */

ret = stat("/mnt/sd0", &stat_buf);
if (ret < 0)
  {
    save_dir = "/mnt/spif";
  }
else
  {
    save_dir = "/mnt/sd0";
  }
```

試しに/mnt/spif 以下にファイルを作成したところ、電源OFF/ONしても消えませんでしたので、たぶん大丈夫なのかと思います。

Answer (score 0):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。
お問い合わせの件について、回答させていただきます。

既にお調べいただいた通り、`/mnt/spif`にFlashの領域が割り当てられております。
例えば、"hoge.txt"というファイルを"/mnt/spif/hoge.txt" というパス名でアクセスすることができます。
ファイル操作は、`fopen`, `fwrite`, `fread`, `fclose` といったC言語標準関数を使うことができます。

以下簡単ではありますが、プログラムの例を記載します。

```
#include 

FILE *fp;

fp = fopen("/mnt/spif/hoge.txt", "w");
fwrite(buf, size, n, fp); // 書き込み
fclose(fp);

fp = fopen("/mnt/spif/hoge.txt", "r");
fread(buf, size, n, fp); // 読み出し
fclose(fp);
```

今後ともSpresenseをどうぞよろしくお願いします。