# Spresenseに予めファイル（*.nnb）を書き込んでおく方法

Tags: spresense, arduino, flash

[Spresenseメインボードのみでのデータ保存](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/52527/spresense%E3%83%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%9C%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%AE%E3%81%BF%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E4%BF%9D%E5%AD%98#)
上記リンクに関連する質問ですが、予めファイルをアップロードしておくことは可能でしょうか。
NNCで学習した.nnbファイルを、SDカードを使用せず内部Flashに格納して使用したいと考えております。
Arduino IDEから書き込めるのが理想的ですが、tools/flash.shなどを使用する格好になるのでしょうか。
（tools/flash.shはブートローダ書き込みで使用されている場合が多く、ユーザファイルの書き込みにも適用できるのでしょうか）
お手数ですがご教示のほど宜しくお願い申し上げます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SDKチュートリアルの自動スクリプトファイルを転送する方法に書かれていたので知りましたが、
https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_tutorials_ja.html#_%E5%8B%95%E4%BD%9C%E7%A2%BA%E8%AA%8D%E8%87%AA%E5%8B%95%E8%B5%B7%E5%8B%95

flash.sh の -w オプションを使えば内蔵Flashへ書き込みできます。

```
$ ./tools/flash.sh -c <port> -w <filepath>
```

`<port>`には、Ubuntuだったら`/dev/ttyUSB0`など、Windowsだったら`COM3`などのCOM番号を指定
`<filepath>`には、転送したいファイルを指定

Spresenseボードの内蔵Flash `/mnt/spif` へコピーされます。

Comment: kzzさん、ありがとうございます！上記の方法で無事書き込み出来、Flash.openで開いて使用することができました！大変助かりましたm(_ _)m